# describir texto de una imagen linea por linea con tesseract

Tags: pytesseract, tesseract

estoy buscando una forma de leer y escribir el texto de una imagen con tesseract, esto es lo que estoy usando pasar de imagen a texto:

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image))

pero necesito que me muestre un mensaje linea por linea.

por ejemplo esta imagen: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/example_01.png, usando esta  imagen quiero que me muestre el siguiente mensaje:
linea 1:noisy image
linea 2:to test
linea 3:tesseract ocr

Answer (score 0):

La función `pytesseract.image_to_string()` por defecto regresa un `string` con saltos de línea `'\n'`.

Si lo que quieres es enumerar las líneas puedes utilizar el siguiente código.

```
text_lines = text.split('\n') 
for line, text in enumerate(text_lines):
    print(line, text)
    text.split('\n')
```

Particiona el `string` por cada salto de linea encontrado y lo guarda en una lista.